How to handle arithmetic operations with extremely large numbers?
I am trying to find the cumulative distribution function of a particular type of order statistics; The progressively censored uniform order statistics. I have produced the following R code:
#The CDF for rth order progressively censored uniform order statistics
n <- 30 #Total number of experimental units
m <- 15 #Desired numbers of failure
R <- c(rep(0, m - 1), n - m) #Progressive censoring scheme
order <- m #Order of the censored order statistics (Here, maximum order)

gam <- NA
Cr <- NA
for(i in 1 : order)
{
  gam[i] <- m - i + 1 + sum(R[i : m])
}
for(i in 1 : order)
{
  Cr[i] <- prod(gam[1 : i])
}
air <- array(dim = c(order, order))

for(i in 1 : order)
{
  for (j in 1 : order) {
    
    if(i != j)
    {
      air[i, j] <- 1/(gam[j] - gam[i])
    }
  }
}
A <- NA
for(i in 1 : order)
{
  A[i] = prod(na.omit(air[i,]))
}
#CDF of progressively censored uniform order statistics
progU_CDF <- function(u)
{
  CDF = NA
  for(i in 1 : length(u))
  {
    CDF[i] <- 1 - (Cr[order] * sum((A/gam) * ((1 - u[i])^(gam))))
  }
  return(CDF)
}

Now, progU_CDF(0) should give 0 and progU_CDF(1) should give 1. Although, in this case, progU_CDF(0) is producing number very close to 0, not exactly 0. Mathematically, the idea is that when u = 0, Cr[order] * sum(A/gam) = 1.
Moreover, when I'm plotting the CDF, the shape is desirable, i.e. monotonically non-decreasing.
plot(seq(0, 1, 0.01), progU_CDF(seq(0, 1, 0.01)), type = "l")

Order Statistics CDF plot n = 30, m = 15
However, things start to go crazy when I take n = 50 and m = 25. Nothing is changed, but Cr[order] * sum(A/gam) is nowhere close to 1 when u = 0. And the CDF plot looks like this:
Order Statistics CDF plot n = 50, m = 25
I suspect this is caused due to the arithmatic operation on extremely large numbers. But I'm unable to trace it.
What's more confusing is that Cr[order] * sum(A/gam) and sum(Cr[order] * A/gam) are producing two different numbers, which are counterintuitive, since Cr[order] is a constant.
My question is, why is it working for n = 30, m = 15 but not for n = 50, m = 25? Is there any way to deal with such large numbers so that Cr[order] * sum(A/gam) is always close to 1 whenever u = 0, no matter the value of n and m?

Please don't post code like rm(list = ls()) in your question - no one wants to run that inadvertently and lose what they're working on.

I'll be careful about that next time. Thanks for pointing out.

A couple notes from first observation - you should look to use R's vectorization rather than loops when possible. Cr <- cumprod(gam) is more efficient and more readable than for(i in 1 : order) { Cr[i] <- prod(gam[1 : i]) }. There are also parts that seem convoluted: when you loop for(i in 1:order) {gam[i] <- m - i + 1 + sum(R[i : m])}, well, R is all 0s except for the last value which is n - m, so sum(R[i:m]) is always n - m. So we can simplify to gam[i] <- m - i + 1 + n - m, which simplifies to n + 1 - i, so you could replace that whole loop with gam <- n + 1 - 1:order.

The cumprod() one is a good suggestion. I'll try to incorporate that. I was trying to write a general code. Here, only the last entry of R is nonzero, but R actually can take any nonzero value as long as n = m + sum(R). So looping was important when I'm working with arbitrary order and arbitrary R. I'll try to make it more readable though. Thanks.

As for precision, I would suggest working on a log scale, there are built-in functions like lfactorial() that work with factorials on the log scale. Alternately, you could use a package designed for exact calculations with large integers such as Rmpfr. But my guess if you work on the log scale you'll be quite precise and very efficient. E.g., on the log scale, log_Cr <- cumsum(log(gam)).

A results in a vector of very small numbers of alternating sign. The errors compound so quickly that performing the calculations in log scale still results in large errors. Multiple precision with Rmpfr seems to be the way to go.
Vectorized with Rmpfr:
library(Rmpfr)

fprogU_CDF <- function(n, m, precBits = 128) {
  R <- c(numeric(m - 1), n - m) #Progressive censoring scheme
  gam <- mpfr(n:(n - m + 1), precBits)
  Cr <- prod(gam)
  air <- -1/outer(gam, gam, "-")
  diag(air) <- 1
  A <- apply(air, 1, prod)
  #CDF of progressively censored uniform order statistics
  function(u) {
    as.numeric(1 - Cr*colSums(A/gam*outer(gam, 1 - u, \(x, y) y^x)))
  }
}

Testing:
progU_CDF1 <- fprogU_CDF(30, 15)
progU_CDF1(0)
#> [1] 2.15461e-27
progU_CDF1(1)
#> [1] 1

progU_CDF2 <- fprogU_CDF(50, 25)
progU_CDF2(0)
#> [1] 2.093805e-18
progU_CDF2(1)
#> [1] 1

progU_CDF3 <- fprogU_CDF(20, 10)
progU_CDF3(0)
#> [1] -2.092626e-32
progU_CDF3(1)
#> [1] 1

progU_CDF4 <- fprogU_CDF(200, 40, 40, 256)
progU_CDF4(0)
#> [1] 1.468873e-24
progU_CDF4(1)
#> [1] 1

curve(progU_CDF1(x), 0, 1, col = "blue", ylab = "CDF", xlab = "u")
curve(progU_CDF2(x), 0, 1, col = "orange", add = TRUE)
curve(progU_CDF3(x), 0, 1, col = "purple", add = TRUE)
curve(progU_CDF4(x), 0, 1, col = "red", add = TRUE)



Alternative Function
A more condensed version that seems to have better precision.
fprogU_CDF <- function(n, m, precBits = 128) {
  d <- mpfr((m - 1):0, precBits)
  g <- mpfr(n:(n - m + 1), precBits)
  C <- factorial(mpfr(n, precBits))/factorial(mpfr(n - m, precBits))/
    factorial(d)/factorial(rev(d))*rev(rep(c(1, -1), length.out = m))/g
  #CDF of progressively censored uniform order statistics
  function(u) as.numeric(1 - colSums(C*outer(g, 1 - u, \(x, y) y^x)))
}

Testing:
progU_CDF1 <- fprogU_CDF(30, 15)
progU_CDF1(0)
#> [1] 0
progU_CDF1(1)
#> [1] 1

progU_CDF2 <- fprogU_CDF(50, 25)
progU_CDF2(0)
#> [1] 0
progU_CDF2(1)
#> [1] 1

progU_CDF3 <- fprogU_CDF(20, 10)
progU_CDF3(0)
#> [1] 0
progU_CDF3(1)
#> [1] 1

progU_CDF4 <- fprogU_CDF(200, 40, 256)
progU_CDF4(0)
#> [1] 3.845097e-25
progU_CDF4(1)
#> [1] 1

curve(progU_CDF1(x), 0, 1, col = "blue", ylab = "CDF", xlab = "u")
curve(progU_CDF2(x), 0, 1, col = "orange", add = TRUE)
curve(progU_CDF3(x), 0, 1, col = "purple", add = TRUE)
curve(progU_CDF4(x), 0, 1, col = "red", add = TRUE)



Thanks a lot! This works exceptionally well! However, I'm still not certain how this works entirely! How do we choose the precbits? Because when I'm using progU_CDF <- fprogU_CDF(20, 10, 128), it gives progU_CDF(0) as 2 and also the CDF curve is monotonically non-increasing. Do we have to manually change the Precbits everytime we change the sample sizes or is there any rule?

Looking more closely at what the function is doing...it's all integer/rational operations until u shows up. The result of 2 for n = 20, m = 10, u = 0 is computed correctly and with precision. If it is supposed to be a value of the CDF at 0, then you should double-check your algorithm.

But when I'm setting n = 20, m = 10, u = 0, without the Rmpfr environment, the progU_CDF(0) gives the value closer to 0, and the CDF plot is also monotonically nondecreasing.  Is this a result of imprecision?

The CDF is properly behaving even without Rmpfr untill the larger sample shows up. I'm trouble understanding why this is happening. If Rmpfr produces 2 for progU_CDF(0), isn’t having  almost 0 for progU_CDF(0) without Rmpfr contradictory?

The problem is solved. I just needed to take the transpose of air in your code. Thanks a lot!

Ah, yes, sorry. I missed that i and j swapped in air[i, j] <- 1/(gam[j] - gam[i]). I updated the answer.
